# How to cycle through all tags in the current file?

Tags: tags

Sometimes I want to just loop through all tags in a file. One use case is for help files, but it's also useful for browsing large unfamiliar source code files.

Is there a way to do this? Something like `:tn`/`:tp` but for *any* tag.

Comment: You can list them with `:tags` but I don't think there's a next/prev to cycle through them one by one. They need to be "named" (`:tag {name}`). Maybe try the "tagbar" plugin and navigate one by one using the side panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do command-line auto-completion with the `:tag` command.

`:tag <tab>`

or

`:tag <ctrl-d>`

These will list ALL the tags.   To narrow down what is included, hit `<tab>` or `<ctrl-d>` after typing a few leading characters or a wildcard pattern.

This requires `:set wildmenu` to be on and will subject to `'wildmenu'` and `'wildoptions'` settings.

Otherwise, this bit of Vimscript will do what you want:
:Tnext  (jump to next tag in the list)
:Tprev  (jump to prev tag in the list)

```
function! TagCycle(direction)
    if !exists('b:tag_number')
        " Initialize
        let b:max_tag_number = len(taglist('.'))-1
        if a:direction=='n'
            let b:tag_number=0
        else
            let b:tag_number = b:max_tag_number
        endif
    else
        if a:direction=='n'
            " Count up
            let b:tag_number+=1
            if b:tag_number > b:max_tag_number
                let b:tag_number = 0
            endif
        elseif a:direction=='p'
            " or count down
            let b:tag_number-=1
            if b:tag_number < 0
                let b:tag_number = b:max_tag_number
            endif
        endif
    endif

    " Jump to tag
    let b:tag_name = taglist('.')[b:tag_number]['name']
    execute 'tag '.b:tag_name
    echo "Tag jump to ".b:tag_name

endfunction

command! Tnext :call TagCycle('n')
command! Tprev :call TagCycle('p')
```

Comment: That's a bit too far from what I am looking for. However, is there some way to get access to the list used for completing `:tag` commands?

Comment: I edited my answer with that sweet Vimscript now included.

Comment: Wow, above and beyond! It seems like `taglist('.')` is what I was looking for in my previous comment, is that right?

Comment: Yes, the `taglist()` function holds all the data of the tags.  It's a list of dictionaries.   It helps to script some helper code around taglist(), like I showed.

Comment: This works great on "regular" code files, but something seems weird about the `taglist` output in help files. I'll have to keep messing with it.

Comment: I figured it out: I needed to filter so that only tags with the current filename were included. Something like: `let l:taglist = filter(taglist('.'), {idx,val -> fnamemodify(val.name, 'p') == expand('%:p')})`