# Sorting `taglist()` output by order of appearance in the file

Tags: tags

As a followup to https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/33176/4674, I found that `taglist()` output seems arbitrarily ordered (maybe alphabetical?).

Right now I'm using this function to get the list of all tags in the current buffer:

```
function TagsInCurrentBuffer() abort
  let l:current_filename = expand('%:p')
  return filter(
    \ taglist('.'),
    \ { idx, val -> fnamemodify(val.filename, 'p') == l:current_filename })
endfunction
```

Is it possible to sort the output of this function according to where the tag appears in the buffer?

Comment: Comment because I don't have code to accompany this: One way would be to map the `.cmd` attribute to a file-position (see the format description in `:help taglist()`—line and line+byte are easy, search requires `searchpos()`, though that only works on the current file?), and then sort the positions

Comment: @D.BenKnoble is correct in general.  Note that since 8.1.2312 it is possible to ask universal ctags and vim to retain the line number of the match, which would make this much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant solution, but this works.

1. Get the tag search patterns
2. Find their line number in the buffer
3. Sort tag names by line number.

```
function TagsInCurrentBuffer() abort
  let current_filename = expand('%:p')

  let taglist_for_buffer = filter( 
      \taglist('.'),
      \ { idx, val -> fnamemodify(val.filename, 'p') == current_filename })

  if len(taglist_for_buffer)==0
      return []
  endif

  let tags_by_line = {}

  for tag_dict in taglist_for_buffer
      " Trim off starting and ending '/' characters from cmd
      let cmd  = tag_dict['cmd'][1:-2]
      let name = tag_dict['name']
      let line_num = searchpos(cmd,'n')[0]
      let tags_by_line[line_num] = name
  endfor

  let sorted_tags = []
  " Sort strings numerically with the 'N' flag
  for line_num in sort(keys(tags_by_line),'N')
      call add(sorted_tags, tags_by_line[line_num])
  endfor

  return sorted_tags

endfunction
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks again! In the future I might try to pre-compute this for certain buffers (e.g. help files) so as to not wastefully re-generate the list on every invocation. But this is plenty good for now.

Comment: Please seem my comment on the question about the possible values of cmd (this will break on absolute positions in tags). That for loop with repeated add calls at the end should also be faster as a mapnew call, something like `keys(tags_by_line)->sort('N')->mapnew({_, v -> tags_by_line[v]})`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Wow, I didn't even recognize that as valid Vimscript.  I haven't started using the `->` method calls and didn't even have mapnew() in my version of Vim yet.   
I just installed 8.2.3364.    I wonder how much of this Vim9 I should embrace.

Comment: This is actually vim8, many enhancements have been made. Im on the fence on vim9; some things are more convenient, and it is faster, that’s for sure. But it’s fairly experimental (read: bugs on the mailing list most days)

Comment: Agreed, mapnew() is (fairly recent) Vim8.   I was thinking about Vim9 because I was looking through git commit history of the 1000+ patches I was behind on.  Lots of Vim9 commits from Bram.